# union for returning default output

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query which may not return anything if there is no match (if uuid and scene_id do not match).

My query:

```
select active  from likes where uuid=12 and scene_id=22
```

so inorder to solve the problem and return 0 in this situation; I am union it with a default value and add 'limit 1' like the following query; but I could not get it work!

```
select * from ((select active  from likes
 where uuid=12 and scene_id=22)as a 
union all
(select 0 as 'active')as b)limit 1;
```

it gives me a syntax error on "as b "

What am I doing wrong in this case?

Please let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: I think you need to remove the keyword `as`. Just add the table alias right after the table (or subquery).

Comment: Without that again I have the error near to ')limit 1'!

Comment: Personally, I'd handle the "no results" situation in the application instead of returning a dummy row from the database. Plus, without an `ORDER BY`, there's no guarantee your `LIMIT` will return the correct row.

Answer (score 0):

I think you overdid the parentheses. This should work:

```
select
  active 
from
  (select active, 0 as importance from likes
   where uuid=12 and scene_id=22
  union all
   select FALSE, 1) x
order by importance
limit 1
```

Note the extra importance column. It makes sure that the actual value from Active is used. Otherwise, the actual row and the default may theoretically be returned in any order.

But I actually agree with Joe Stefanelli's comment, that your application should handle this rather than your query.

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7cfbe3/1

Comment: This one returns BLOB

Comment: This one returns the type of the Active field in your table.

Comment: Thanks! Actually I did not overdid parantheses! I copied your query! so why is it returning the type of Active field?

Comment: What type is Active in your table?

Comment: Bit is the data type –

Comment: sorry do you knwo how I can get the real value not BLOB? Thanks

Comment: Yes. I've modified the query. Use FALSE instead of 0.

Comment: Actually still it is giving BLOB; btw the exact type of active column is BIT(1) does it matter? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change your query as below (remove the inner table alias)

```
select * 
from 
(    
select active  from likes where uuid=12 and scene_id=22

union all

select BIN(0) as 'active'
) tab limit 1;
```

Problem was that, `active` is of bit type and in second select 0 is INT type. Just convert 0 to binary representation using `BIN()` function.

Comment: Why am I getting BLOB; how cna I solve it in this case? Thanks

Comment: even your query gives BLOB

Comment: @user3399784, what's the data type of `active`?

Comment: @user3399784 I think it's of BLOB type and hence you are getting the same.

Comment: Actually still it is giving BLOB; btw the exact type of active column is BIT(1) does it matter? Thanks